# Strip path from find for use in pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm trying to use "find" to execute a command on a bunch of HTML files and then pipe out the result to a different directory.  However, the pipe is failing because the filename found by "find" includes the path, and the path does not fit the directory structure of the pipe target.  Essentially I need to strip the path from the second instance of {} below.

```
find subd/*.html -type f -exec "./mycmd {} opts > subd2/{}" \;
```

This is a simplified version of the command, but in the real world, putting a "../" before mysubdirectory2 will not work, nor does prefixing "cd subd && ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution in the end, which was to use single quotes rather than double quotes, and use the $() evaluation form for basename:

```
find subd/*.html -type f -exec './mycmd {} opts > subd2/$(basename {})' \;
```

I have no idea why single quotes are the difference, or any idea why Andy's solution did not work on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Jonathan's solution, but remove the unnecessary extra script.

```
find subd -name '*.html' -type f -exec sh -c '
    for f; do
        ./mycmd "$f" opts > subd2/"${f##*/}"
    done
' _ {} '+'
```

Answer (score 1):

Time to write a script (call it `mycmd-invoker`) that does the 'correct job' and run that from `find`:

```
find subd/*.html -type f -exec mycmd-invoker {} +
```

The script gets given a list of file names with path and can deal with the issues:

```
for file in "$@"
do
    base=$(basename "$file")
    ./mycmd "$file" opts > subd2/"$base" 
done
```

You can throw the `mycmd-invoker` script away once you're done with the task, unless you think you might need to do it again.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to work:

```
while read fn
do
  ./mycmd "${fn}" opts > "subd2/${fn##*/}"
done < <(find subd -type f -name "*.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find subd/*.html -type f -exec "./mycmd {} opts > subd2/\`basename {}\`" \;
```

Update: Added escapes before backticks surrounding basename

Comment: Basename doesn't seem to do what I imagine we both think it should do in this context.  For some reason it doesn't strip out the path.

Comment: In this particular case, I think `basename {}` is run *before* `find`, and it's output (likely empty, but maybe an error message) is substituted into the double-quoted string, resulting in `find subd/*.html -type f -exec "./mycmd {} opts > subd2/" \;`

Comment: Very good points.  I have updated it to escape the backticks, and in my testing this is a working solution.

Comment: I'm getting some really funny results out of basename.  Whether I use `basename {}` or $(basename {}) doesn't seem to strip out the path info.  I can't find anything on the net about times when basename doesn't strip out the path.  Simple example: find www/*.html -type f -exec sh -c "echo `basename {}`" \; returns www/channel.html, 
www/definition.html, 
www/empty.html, 
www/index.html, 
etc.

Comment: Yet if I call the function directly: echo `basename "www/index.html"`
 it simply returns index.html, so something is going on with the way it is sent through as {} from find...

Comment: Ok, I found the solution which works on my machine, and that was to use single quotes rather than double quotes.  I have no idea why this is, but thanks for your response!